# How to use React / Angular chatbot into another angular 14 project

Tags: reactjs, angular, react-hooks, chatbot

I have an angular 14 project. I want to build a chatbot into react / Angular, Then I wanted to bring it into the angular 14 projects. How can I do that?

Like in the angular 14 frontend project I wanted to bring the chatbot in index.html, Like ---

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
            Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
        (function () {
            var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
                s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s1.async = true;
            s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/634c4e2cdaff0e1306d24815/1gfh12omj';
            s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
        })();
    </script>
    <!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

Example of Twak.

I know using socket.io, and Nodejs we can build Chatbot. But How can I bring that chatbot into another project, something like above example.

I don't want to use an iframe.

I did not find any article or youtube link on the same. If you have please feel free to share it.

Already build this chatbot in react -

https://spanion-chat.netlify.app

Project link - https://github.com/codeztech-atique/chart-bot-with-nodejs

Any help would be appriciated.